# How to filter data from all the records when the records are paginated?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, postgresql, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot app where I am using Postgres for my data storage,I am using pagination to structure my data.

I recieve data like this:

```
{
"messages": {
"dtoList": [
{
"acknowledge_msg": "null",
"status": "QUEUED",
"msg_id": 2021082012204616000,
},
{
"acknowledge_msg": "null",
"status": "QUEUED",
"msg_id": 2021082012204575500,
},
],
"totalRecords": 4,
"pageSize": 2,
"pageNumber": 1,
"numPages": 2
}},
```

Now in my react page,when I will navigate to pages,I will simple do this api call with page size and page number and It will give me a response.

Now I want to apply filters but filters need to filter from all the records not from respective pages.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The only way I see is to rely on the backend. Does the API expose a way to filter the data? If not, you'll have to ask to the backend developers to implement it

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve, regards only the backend, not the reactjs application.

You should send to your spring-boot application the query you would like to perform, then apply it into your postregsql query. It would update also pagination, since less results will be presented.

Maybe show here your frontend code, instead of the JSON data, and it would be easier to help you applying the remote filters.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said before, the only proper way to achieve this is to do that on backend.

You can, of course, read all of the pages and filter them in frontend, but this is an awful solution